# How to order useEffect hooks with fetch

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 useEffect in my App, like this:

```
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetchData(fetchStr)
      .then((data) => { setItems(data) })
      .then(() => { setLoading(false) });
  }, [dependencyA]);

  useEffect(()=> if (!loading){
   setItems(...)
   setAnotherState(...) 
 ,[dependencyA, dependencyB])}
```

Both parts is far more complicated and to me they can't be merged into one single `useEffect`
I have some `console.log` in both `useEffect`, so I know the second `useEffect` log sooner than the first. What can I do to ensure that the second will only be called after the first being done with it's fetch things. Both have same `dependencyA`, but the latter have additional `dependencyB`.

Comment: Are these doing asynchronous things?

Comment: If the code is dependent maybe you should combine them into one useEffect

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Without a use case, this problem is not clear unfortunately.

Comment: The first is used to fetch data from the server, and the second is for mutating states which related to data from the first fetch.

Answer (score 2):

you can add a state and set it to true after the first effect completed and then add that state in the second effect and olnly run the effect if that state is true.

```
const [isDone, setIsDone] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
// Do something 
setIsDone(true)
},[dependencyA]) 
useEffect(() => {
if(!isDone) return;
// Do something 
setIsDone(true)
},[dependencyA, dependencyB, isDone])
```

Comment: Nice idea though, I think that will work

Comment: It doesn't work though, the second `useEffect` still executes first

Comment: @chaukhoa97 can you share your code?

Comment: I have already update the question